# Open Laszlo and Fusion Charts

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts, openlaszlo

I'm just curious to know if anyone has used (successfully) Fusion Charts with Open Laszlo... especially in the DHTML/HTML5. I'd like to be able to insert a chart into a view/window laszlo component and still be able to resize and such. This certainly should be able to be done using Javascript... but my javascript skills are a little lacking.

Also, it looks like this could be done by embedding HTML in a frame of sorts in Open Laszlo. Having trouble with the  tag though.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, my solution was to use a different technology stack. Open Laszlo's community is pretty small and it seems there are few people that use the framework anymore. Most move on to Adobe or HTML5/javascript solutions.

Should somebody come up with an answer, I'll unmark this and select theirs.